# Delphi Component Editor Verb is not executed

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, delphi-xe

I've made a `Component Editor` for my custom `tLabel`. Double clicking works fine, but right clicking on the component and selectind the corresponding `Verb` does nothing. The menu item is enabled, but the `ExecuteVerb` procedure is not triggered.

Follows the code:

```
unit LabelComponentEditor;

interface

uses
  Classes, DesignerTypes, DesignMenus, Dialogs,  
  DesignEditors, DesignIntf, Forms, Menus,
  CustomLabel;

type
  tLabelComponentEditor = class(tComponentEditor)
  private
    procedure Edit; override;
    procedure ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
    function GetVerb(Index: Integer): string; override;
    function GetVerbCount: Integer; override;
    procedure PrepareItem(Index:  Integer; const aItem : iMenuItem); override;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponentEditor (tCustomLabel, tLabelComponentEditor);
end;

procedure tLabelComponentEditor.Edit;
begin
  inherited;
  frmLabelDialog := tfrmLabelDialog.Create (Application);
  frmLabelDialog.ShowModal;
  frmLabelDialog.Free;
end; { Edit }

procedure tLabelComponentEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); 
begin
  inherited;
  frmLabelDialog := tfrmLabelDialog.Create (Application);
  case Index of
    0 : begin
      frmLabelDialog.ShowModal;
      frmLabelDialog.Free;
    end;
  end;
end; { ExecuteVerb }

function tLabelComponentEditor.GetVerb (Index: Integer) : string;
begin
  case Index of
    0 : Result := 'Edit component'; // checked: this is executed
  end;
end; { GetVerb }

function tLabelComponentEditor.GetVerbCount : Integer;
begin
  Result := 1; // checked: this is executed
end; { GetVerbCount }

procedure tLabelComponentEditor.PrepareItem(Index: Integer; const aItem: iMenuItem);
begin
  case Index of
    0 : aItem.Enabled := True; // to see if 'ExecuteVerb' should trigger 
                               //   but in fact, made no difference
  end;
end; { PrepareItem }

end.
```

Comment: when you compiled it, weren't there any warnings about new "ExecuteVerb" hiding the method from parent class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify `override` on your `ExecuteVerb()` method.  Double-clicking calls the `Edit()` method, which you did `override`.

Also, since you only have 1 verb defined, you don't need to use `case` statements in your methods, since the `Index` will always be 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was really a stupid from me. I would look at the code my entire life and didn't see the error. The `case` statment was a desperate attempt to see if anything would work.

Comment: `case` here might be a good thing for defensive programming and a scaffolding for future extending. It is not required, but there is nothing bad in it either.